# How to optimize the Cartesian product

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, cartesian-product

I need to do a Cartesian product of one table but without the same rows. Now I have:

```
select * 
From T_Car C1
Join T_Car C2 On C1.CarID <> C2.CarID
```

But for T_Car table with 1300 rows it takes almost 2 min.
I tried to use OPTION (HASH JOIN) and OPTION (MERGE JOIN) but this end up with error:

Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

Is there any possibility to optimize this query?

Comment: You are aware how freaking many results that will return? (1.69 million rows if I'm not mistaken.) The obvious optimization would be: Dont' select so much stuff.

Comment: @delnan, there's a where clause, I believe it would only be 1,687,400 :-). Why do you want to do a Cartesian product? There's probably a better solution to your problem.

Comment: @Ben I accounted for that originally, but with most rounding methods the result stays the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please elaborate on the why?
The query you mentioned is not a common one (from my experience) and it will result with an expensive query plan. If we'll get a better understanding of the context of the query we may take a different approach that will result with increased performance, maybe querying a stored procedure that performs several steps to retrieve relevant data, but does it in an efficient way for each stage.

A good example for this (using your scenario) would be to create a procedure that isolates the relevant IDs to a temp table and then joins it (using '=' instead of '<>') to get the results.

Comment: I want to find similar rows in T_Car table. So i need compare one row with others.

Comment: when you say similar, I guess you talk about wishing to compare the other columns of the table? Is that the case?

Comment: @user927524 please define "similar" - nobody else here has any clue what you mean.

Comment: The main purpose of this query is to find the all duplicates. E.g two cars are duplicates when engine number is the same, but it can also be duplicatetes when the producernt, model, color, date of production is the same. The conditions which I have given are two of many. So I have to compare each row with the rest of the other rows.

Comment: @user927524 I think I understand better now, but one more question. Let's say you have a duplicate of a record, would all the columns be a duplicate (except the identity) or can you have a situation where only the engine number is a duplicate and other columns are different between the two rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to join every row you can use a INNER JOIN or a LEFT JOIN. A Inner JOIN returns only the matching row and a Left Join returns also empty rows of the left table. A Right Join returns also empty rows of the right table.

Answer (score 0):

How long does it take to produce the entire Cartesian product, with 1,690,000 rows in it?

If that's a reasonable amount of time, then consider using the MINUS operator to eliminate the rows where the primary key matches. Something like.

```
select *  From T_Car C1, T_Car C2 
MINUS
select *  From T_Car C1 Join T_Car C2 On C1.CarID = C2.CarID
```

It's likely that the entire Cartesian product will take too long to produce.  Why do you need such a result anyway?  Maybe there's a better way to model your data.

Comment: Please note that SQL Server uses EXCEPT instead of MINUS (which comes from Oracle) if I'm not mistaken.